# How to add none values to Python Dataclass?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Let's say I have a python Dataclass:

```
@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int  
    married: bool
```

And I add data to the fields say from an imaginary dictionary:

```
for row in something:
    ob = Person(
        name=row.name,
        age=row.age,
        married=row.married,
     )
```

How do I, for example, make `name` equal to `None` or an empty string if `name` is not given in the imaginary dictionary?

I tried something like:

```
name = row.name if row.name else None
```

but I got an Attribute error like: `AttributeError: object has no attribute 'name'`

**Edit**: I want to achieve this without necessarily setting the fields in the `Person` dataclass to `None`

Comment: If it was an imaginary *dictionary*, you'd use `row['name']`, and if that key didn't exist, you'd use `row.get('name')` to get the desired effect. With any random object, the equivalent is `getattr(row, 'name', None)`.

Comment: The attribute error is the real problem. What is the type of `row` here? If it's a dictionary you could try `name = row['name'] if 'name' in row else None`

Comment: @h0r53 `row.get('name')` already encapsulates that pattern.

Comment: @deceze I solved it with `getattr(row, 'name', None)`. Thank you!

Comment: @h0r53 @Rivers `row` is a namedTuple.